# How do I raise every element in a list to its corresponding index number?

Tags: python, list, enumeration, exponentiation

So if the input is `[3, 2, 5]`, the output would be `[1, 2, 25]`, and if the input was `[5, 10, 20]`, the output would be `[1, 10, 400]` (5^0, 10^1, 20^2)

Comment: Please show what you've tried in order to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Have you tried looping over the list, and raising each element to the indices power?

Comment: use list comprehension and the enumerate function

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a map between your input list and a range.

```
def raise_power(input_list):
    return list(map(lambda x,y: x**y, input_list, range(len(input_list))))
```

Or a more straightforward way (suggested by @roganjosh) to put it could be :

```
def raise_power(input_list):
    return [i**x for x, i in enumerate(input_list)]
```

Both have no significant difference in computation time. (see comments)

Comment: Seems overkill when you could just do `a = [i**x for x, i in enumerate([5, 10, 20])] `

Comment: Sure, your solution works too and is more pythonic :-). No idea about speed though

Comment: Sorry, first timings were incorrect. But the corrected timings show no difference. With a list of 1000 values: mine: `7.34 ms ± 70.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` and yours: `7.38 ms ± 9.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: Thanks for running that. I guess it's a matter of style then :-)

Comment: No, I meant what I put. Your change to my code does not give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way is use a loop like following

```
for i in range(0,len(input)):
print(input[i]**i)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your own solution is neither correct nor pythonic . Here is your code will fail :

So if my input is :

```
3 2 5 3 2 5
```

output should be :

```
[1, 2, 25, 27, 16, 3125]
```

But your code will give :

```
[1, 2, 25, 1, 2, 25]
```

Because after 3,2,5 when again 3 comes in the list then index(i) will choose first 3 in the list not second 3 or third or any. So index will always choose first appear numbers and hence you will get the wrong output.

The right way is use enumerate :

```
print([j**i for i,j in enumerate([int(i) for i in input().split()])])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 25, 27, 16, 3125]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input into a list, then use enumerate to get the index position and the value. Since the value will be a string, use int to convert and then raise it to the power.

```
x = input('Enter the list of numbers : ')
y = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')]
print ([int(a)**i for i,a in enumerate(y)])
```

Code output will be:

```
Enter the list of numbers : 3,2,5
[1, 2, 25]
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out myself!  I'm sure you are all very proud.  The below code will produce the output I'm looking for.  Thank you though!

> ```
> firstlist = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
> newlist = [i ** (int(firstlist.index(i))) for i in firstlist]
> ```

Comment: You don't really need to lookup for finding the right indices as you know they'll come sorted... thus the use of `enumerate` suggested by @roganjosh below

Comment: I think this will give the wrong answer for `[1, 2, 2]`.